# Can't install mysql server on ubuntu 18.04 because packages are not configured

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, dpkg

I want to install a mysql server. Eventually I want to run PHP scripts and I read that I need an sql server for that and mysql seems to be the recommended choice.

I tried to run`$ sudo apt install mysql-server` from the terminal. I remember that it did not  install mysql satisfactorily. When I ran `$ sudo systemctl status mysql` it told me that the server was `inactive (dead)`. I read some posts of people [reporting the same thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068949/cannot-reinstall-mysql), and realised that `/etc/mysql` was not removed with the purge `$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server*`
. So I force-deleted it with root permisson. Maybe it wasn't a good idea, I don't know. Now I'm having trouble to even install the mysql server again.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-config-mailtransport kf5-kdepim-apps-libs-data kio-ldap kio-sieve
  libgrantlee-templates5 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libical2 libkf5akonadiagentbase5
  libkf5akonadicalendar-data libkf5akonadicalendar5abi2 libkf5akonadicontact-data
  libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5abi1
  libkf5akonadimime-data libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes-data
  libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5
  libkf5akonadiwidgets5 libkf5alarmcalendar-data libkf5alarmcalendar5abi1
  libkf5calendarcore5abi1 libkf5calendarsupport-data libkf5calendarsupport5abi1
  libkf5calendarutils-bin libkf5calendarutils-data libkf5calendarutils5abi1
  libkf5contacteditor-data libkf5contacteditor5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5
  libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5eventviews-data
  libkf5eventviews5 libkf5identitymanagement-data libkf5identitymanagement5abi1
  libkf5imap-data libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditor-bin libkf5incidenceeditor-data
  libkf5incidenceeditor5abi2 libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kontactinterface-data
  libkf5kontactinterface5 libkf5ldap-data libkf5ldap5 libkf5libkdepim-data
  libkf5libkdepim-plugins libkf5libkdepim5abi2 libkf5libkdepimakonadi5
  libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5abi2 libkf5mailtransportakonadi5
  libkf5mbox5 libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2 libkf5pimcommon-plugins
  libkf5pimcommon5abi3 libkf5pimcommonakonadi5 libkf5pimtextedit-data
  libkf5pimtextedit5abi2 libkgantt2 libkgantt2-l10n libkolabxml1v5 libkpimgapi-data
  libkpimgapicalendar5 libkpimgapicontacts5 libkpimgapicore5 libkpimgapitasks5
  libkpimkdav-data libkpimkdav5 libkpimsmtp5 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 libqt5webengine5
  linux-headers-4.15.0-64 linux-headers-4.15.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-64-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-64-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-64-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure- 
symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
previous failure.
                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it seems I got a dpkg error with `mysql-server-5.7` and one with `mysql-server`. Somehow things are not configured properly. This is beyond my capabilities. How can one install a mysql server?

Comment: Seems like this would be better asked on either [dba.se] or [ubuntu.se]. This isn't programming related, this is installation and Database/OS Administration related.

Comment: Great! Okay, thanks.

Comment: [Cross Post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1211092/597903) on [Ubuntu.se].

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to cross post, but didn't find any button. Might be a good idea to have a button for that... anyways, thanks.